# QueryDSL replacing "on" with keyword "with"

Tags: querydsl

I am joining unrelated tables. QueryDSL looks like this:

```
  .leftJoin(user, us).on(us.id.in(
                JPAExpressions
                    .select(user.id)
                    .from(user)
                    .innerJoin(user.authorities, authority)
                        .on(authority.name.eq(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN)
                            .and(user.oj.eq(sub.oj)))
            ));
```

but output I am getting is this:

```
  left join user r with r.id in
 (select user.id from User user inner join user.authorities as authority with authority.name = ?1 and user.oj= sub.oj)
```

Why is `on` being replace with "`with`"?

Answer (score 0):

QueryDSL's Hibernate integration was never updated for JPA 2.1+ and still uses Hibernates proprietary WITH keyword, which offers less functionality. I have proposed a PR for better Hibernate 5 support in https://github.com/querydsl/querydsl/pull/2604, which since has been integrated, but is not released yet.

Meanwhile, you can probably work around it by using the `JPATemplates` instead of the `HQLTemplates` which are used by default for Hibernate. The  `JPATemplates`  provide saner defaults for modern Hibernate versions.

You can specify the templates with your query factory or constructor: `new JPAQuery(entityManager, JPATemplates.INSTANCE)`.